# Saving results of radio button click in Flask

Tags: python, flask, radio-button

The relevant part of my flask code is:

```
@app.route("/process", methods = ["GET", "POST"] )
def process_form():
    #checked = request.form.getlist('option')
    checked=request.form('option')
    with open('checked.txt','w') as file:
        file.write("%s"%checked)
    # do something with checked array
    return checked
```

and my html looks like:

```
<div class="container" id='tog'>
     <div class="half">
        <form action="/process" method="POST">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="original" />
        <h3>originak value<h3>
    </div>

    <div class="half"> 
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="freq" />
        <h3>Term Freq<h3>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

The idea is that I want to find out which radio button was selected and store the information is  a text file. But that does not seem to be working.

I changed the html to:

```
<form action="/process" method="POST">    
    <div class="half">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="original" />           
    </div>
    <div class="half">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="freq" />           
    </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

and now I get a `400 Bad Request` error

Comment: you are using `request.form('option')` you should probably use either `request.form['option']` or `request.form.get('option')`

Comment: tried both, did not work, I'm not getting any errors though ...

Comment: What does "does not seem to be working" mean? Is the form submitting? Is the file created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a submit button inside of your form. Add one.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
```

Also, you probably want to change `request.form('option')` to `request.form['option']`

Comment: tried, and now I am getting a `400 Bad Request` error

Comment: Did you change request.form('option') to request.form['option'] ?

Comment: it was  typo, was calling `request.form['action']` instead of `request.form['option']` but I also had forgotten the submit type, thank you